# How to get a,b,c when a^b, b^c and c^a is given

Tags: boolean, xor, boolean-expression

I am solving a puzzle which goes like this.

> Suppose you have three pen drives P1, P2 and P3 each having 1GB capacity. You have 3GB data. You have to divide these data into P1, P2 and P3 such that if any one of the pen drive among P1, P2, P3 got crashed than you should be able to recover all the data from remaining two pen drives.

Solution for the problem is like this:

> Suppose the 3GB data is divided into three groups A, B and C. Then the distribution would be like this

```
P1-> A^B
P2-> B^C
P3-> C^A
```

I am not understanding how to get the values of A, B and C variables if A^B, B^C and C^A are given.

Comment: This is not a programming question, so off topic for Stackoverflow. Try a Math Stackexchange next time, or otherwise see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin  But you might want to try searching "RAID 5"

Comment: Also, did you lift this question directly from geeks for geeks? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/puzzle-data-recovery-problem/). It has its own comments section so why don't you just ask there? Please stop spamming Stack Overflow for this stuff

Answer (score 0):

p1, p2 and p3 only tell you if a==b, b==c and c==a, respectively.
That means you can't really conclude from p1, p2, p3 to a, b, c.
But if you know the value of say a, then knowing p1 you can calculate b and by knowing p3 you can calculate c.